# problem on numbering of equations

Tags: syntax

I am trying to write equations in latex:

See this following code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
}


\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Matsushima Theorem}
\section{jishnu ray}

\begin{equation}


 [x_i,x_j]=\sum_{m< a\leqslant n}c_{ij}^ax_a,[x_a,x_i]=\sum_jc_{a,i}^ix_j 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

it behaves unusual.. Why?

Comment: remove the `$` you are already in math

Comment: ok. but it does not help.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that will allow us to see all the code that may be causing the problem.

Comment: @gopal yes it does help.  If you make a complete document, starting with `\documentclass` and remove the `$` then you will get no error and a numbered equation.

Comment: @gopal now you see why you should not edit the question to ask an unreleated question, you should ask a new question, this page now has two answers that are each correct but answer completely unrelated problems. It just makes it confusing for later readers. (If you delete the original `$` example I will delete my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the white space in

```
\begin{equation}


 [x_i,x_j]=\sum_{m< a\leqslant n}c_{ij}^ax_a,[x_a,x_i]=\sum_jc_{a,i}^ix_j 
\end{equation}
```

[image]